# If gas limit is too low is still part of the contract executed?

Tags: transactions, gas-limit, out-of-gas

Basically my question is, let's say a smart contract requires 50k of gas and I set my gas limit to 25k, is it an atomic operation or does it execute part of the contract until gas runs out?

Answer (score 1):

If you run out of gas, all the changes to the state get reversed.

Comment: Except transaction's used gas.